# How to fixed error on ContentUri OpenCV4Android?

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, grayscale

someone can help me ? This is my project

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {     
  String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
  int column_index = cursor
  .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  return cursor.getString(column_index);
 }
```

but I try this, still error

```
 public String getPath(Uri uri) {    
   String res = null;
   String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
   Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection, null, null, null);
   if(cursor.moveToFirst()){;
     int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
     res = cursor.getString(column_index);
   }
   cursor.close();
   return res;
}
```

What should I do?  In LogCat still show error and can't process image

> No implementation found for long org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread_0(java.lang.String, int) (tried Java_org_opencv_highgui_Highgui_imread_10 and Java_org_opencv_highgui_Highgui_imread_10__Ljava_lang_String_2I)

Comment: Can you show the snippet where you use `imread`?

Comment: int gray = Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE;
img_awal = Highgui.imread(selectedImagePath, gray); here @Miki. What should i do ?

Comment: Try `Imgcodecs.imread(...)`. Which OpenCV version are you using?

Comment: i using openCV version 2.4.9 @Miki

Comment: still error and can't running @Miki

Comment: Yep, that is for opencv 3

Comment: so, what should i do ? change library or ? @Miki

Comment: You're probably not loading OpenCV correctly. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597805/imread-wont-work-in-opencv-with-android)

Comment: it will help sir ? im so confused @Miki

Comment: I don't develop in Java... sorry. Be sure to load OpenCV correctly with something like `static{ System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); }`. Check [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d52/tutorial_java_dev_intro.html#gsc.tab=0) for more details. Good luck!